# I can't run the last command of Kade Engine. It errors

Tags: compiler-errors, haxe, lime-haxe

So i have a problem when installing Kade Engine. When i try to run the last command, it errors.
it says :
"C:\Users\User\msvc\extension-webm\git\project>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Warning: Could not find Visual Studio 2017 VsDevCmd
Missing HXCPP_VARS
Error: Could not automatically setup MSVC"
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You must download MSVC v142 - 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools and Windows SDK (10.0.17763.0)

Also u need to download Visual Studio Community to download those.

--11/21

- lime rebuild extension-webm <windows, mac, linux>

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. I found a solution. It turns out i didn't install the VS Tools for Windows at the github page. I installed that 19 gigabytes of junk and i was able to run "lime rebuild extension-webm windows". I hope this answer helped those who had the same problem with me.